# How can I remove sharp edges from the final render?

Tags: mesh, uv, normals, texture-baking, topology

I'm un-wrapping my mesh and these are all my mark seams:

[image]

[image]

When I render these are the results:

[image]

It seems pretty god, but when I went in the back, near the neck I saw them, straches all long my mark seams.

[image]

Did I make something wrong or is it usual with mark seams? What can I do in order to smooth this one and render my figure better?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the artifacts on the third picture aren't relevant to UV seams Arrows point to the seam in mesh topology which isn't what seams can change. The seams will change UV map but not geometry. Probably you should revise something with it (only if that's not grey texture on the mesh applied using those seams).

Comment: Please show a close up of the defective area with the vertices showing and an illuminating angle.  Solid and See transparent .... show all edges.  Not final render.  Edit Mode or Object mode in 3D View Window.

Comment: I have already edit mate

Comment: i did the low poly and then mark seams. I baked the high poly onto the low poly, so yes there is the normal map of high poly

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't any internal geometry in the highpoly before you baked it ? Check the lowpoly for that too. You could [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) this part of mesh if anyone is willing to help.

Comment: Sorry but i would like to keep my file. I have just checked and there wasn't any internal geometry. Do you think bias could help me? I have set it at 0.101. Should i increase it?

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles?

Comment: Yes! No Doubles founded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the "Margin Overdraw" setting in bake? Make sure your texture is large enough, set the overdraw to 64 pixels, and make sure there is at least a 64 pixel gap around the seams in the UV layout.

This is a typical problem with UV-steams. It is called "texture tearing", and it happens because at the UV seam there is a texture discontinuity.

Select the vertex at the black mark in the center of the spine. Then open the UV editor and look at the location of that point. You'll see that it is at a corner of a UV island, and probably surrounded by empty black. That black on the other side of the seam is blending in and making the black tear.

It can help to over-draw UV seam in the texture, so there is similar data on both sides of the seam line, for all UV islands. If you can get the over-draw color substantially similar, then you won't see the seam line.

It can sometimes help if you increase the resolution of your textures.

Let's consider why the tear happens in detail...

Every rendered pixel you see is filtering some number of nearby texture pixels together. For simplicity, let's just assume it's filtering a circle of texture pixels together around a UV location.

When we're not near a seam, it has a clean circle of pixels around the UV location. When we move to an adjacent UV location, it's the new circle overlaps the old one so the output pixel gradually varies from it's neighbor.

However, at the seam edge, half the circle falls across the seam and outside the UV island. Ideally that other half would be exactly the same pixels which are on the other side of the UV seam, but those pixels are located somewhere *else* in our texture. In fact, the other side of the circle might just fall onto blank black pixels!

Ideally, the pixels over the edge of every seam would match the pixels on the other side of that seam. Both the bake tools and texture-paint tools *try* to approximate this using a setting called "Overdraw".

Answer (score 0):

Delete the vertex of the defective area.  Examine for unwanted pixels.  Add back a new pixel.  Correct Seams if required.

Examine the troublesome area in question in Mesh Select Mode vertex, edge, and face view while in Edit mode and remove, adjust stray vertices.

Comment: Sorry i did understand; can you explai better? Thank you